# onAdOpened() / onAdLeftApplication() not being called when clicked on the ad

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I making an ad request to Google Mobile Ads SDK and set the AdListener to listen for the ad events.  However for some ads onAdOpened() / onAdLeftApplication() is not being called and I'm unable to display the ad in the external web browser. Instead I can interact with the ad within the ad view. Is there anything I can do using the SDK to always open the ad in the external application?

Here is the AdView:

```
final AdView adView = new AdView(activity);
adView.setAdSize(adSize);
adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        String error = "";
        switch (errorCode) {
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            error = "ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR. Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST:
            error = "ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST. The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR:
            error = "ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR. The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.";
            break;
            case AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:
                    error = "ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL. The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.";
                    break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdOpened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdClosed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdLeftApplication");
        }
    });
```

and load the ad:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new   AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice(deviceid).build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Can you supply some code. Your question doesn't quite jell.

Comment: Also you mention an external web browser, are you in cordova? Are you using `com.admob.google` admob ads cordova plugin?

Comment: It's not cordova, android. I have added some code. The ad is loading properly.After clicking on it, onAdOpened() should be called and the ad should open in an browser. But for some ads onAdOpened() is not called and I can interact with the ad within the view. I'm wondering if this is how the ad is set or I can control it through the sdk

Comment: it's com.google.android.gms.ads

Answer (score -2):

```
 adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    public void onAdLeftApplication (){
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t1.setText("5000");

    }
}
```